# Подскажите как настроить ispconfig3+bitrix

Tags: битрикс, настройка, config, isp

Подскажите как настраивается сайты в панели IspConfig3 если они с одной админкой на Bitrix, (композитные сайты)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете сайт в панели согласно [документации](http://docs.ispconfig.org/creating-web-sites/) затем по [документации](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=39) Битрикса о переводе сайта на композит делаете настройку сайта и сервера.